# Is it possible to dump a python fixture in runtime?

Tags: python, json, django

I have this test case:

```
def test_ingest_projects(self):
    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'projects.csv')
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        projects = []
        for row in reader:
            row['effort'] = float(row['effort'])
            projects.append(Project(**row))
        Project.objects.bulk_create(projects)
        print(Project.objects.all())
```

After running it I want to dump a json fixture of the Project table, is this possible on runtime?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, I believe.

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize

json_string = serialize('json', Project.objects.all())
```